# Any replacement of chatter API for Download URL e.g. "/services/data/v32.0/chatter/files/06917000000XXXXAAA/content?versionNumber=1"

Tags: rest-api, chatter, rest

I want to download the file or ContentDocument using non-chatter REST API. I have explored that we can download any ContentDocument or file by using following kind of chatter REST API (which is actually downloadUrl):

"/services/data/v32.0/chatter/files/06917000000XXXXAAA/content?versionNumber=1"

But I don't want to use chatter API (like above example) to download the file because chatter API has very less quota to call.

So, Is there any other method to download the file except the above mentioned method.

Thanks,
Zeeshan

Answer (score 1):

The `06917000000XXXXAAA` in the URL is the ContentDocument ID, and the `versionNumber=1` is the version number of the [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm). You can use a SOQL query to get the binary data:

```
SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId='069...' AND VersionNumber=n
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your soql on workbench like following:

/services/data/v32.0/query/?q=SELECT+VersionData+FROM+ContentVersion+WHERE+ContentDocumentId='069170000006t37AAA'+AND+VersionNumber='1'

Comment: And got link of VersionData in response:
{
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "ContentVersion",
      "url" : "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/068170000006qsFAAQ"
    },
    "VersionData" : "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/068170000006qsFAAQ/VersionData"
  } ]
}

Comment: But when I tried VersionData link then got only this response:

"Raw Response

1"

Comment: I have read the Documentation about VersionData that it contains base64 encoded data, but I am not getting anything like it

Comment: Can you try using curl to test things out, as described in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm? The VersionData URL should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked and sorry for very late reply I was involved in solving urgent task

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file by forming the URL

> https://yourDomain.lightning.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/ContentVersionId

Get the contentVersion ID of the file you want to download and form the above url. that URL will download if the file's Extension has **Download** behavior set up in **File Upload and Download Security**
[image]

If it has **execute in browser** it will preview.